# Correct way to load image into UIWebView from NSData object

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsdata

I have downloaded a gif image into an NSData object (I've checked the contents of the NSData object and it's definitely populated). Now I want to load that image into my UIWebView. I've tried the following:

```
[webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

but I get a blank UIWebView. Loading the image from the same URL directly works fine:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
[imageView loadRequest:request];
```

Do I need to set the textEncodingName to something, or am I doing something else wrong?

I want to load the image manually so I can report progress to the user, but it's an animated gif, so when it's done I want to show it in a UIWebView.

Edit: Perhaps I need to wrap my image in HTML somehow? Is there a way to do this without having to save it to disk?

Comment: rusty, I use the first line of your code to display a local gif image and it works fine. Looks like the method is ok.

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 23):

I tested the code with PNG ("image/png"), JPG ("image/jpeg") and GIF ("image/gif"), and it works as expected:

```
[webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:imageMIMEType textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Now, what's wrong with your app?

- the imageData is not a well-formed image data. Try opening the file with a web browser or an image editor to check it.
- the MIME type is incorrect. Look at the first bytes of the data to determine the actual file type.
- webView is not connected in IB, is nil, is hidden, is covered with another view, is off screen, has a CGRectZero frame, etc.

Comment: i want to show png file.is it possible using this code?

Answer (score 6):

I did not really try to load image to UIWebView but a google search gives me. I think your image string must have a good path and looks like a URL

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *HTMLData = @"
<h1>Hello this is a test</h1>
<img src="sample.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" />";
[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];
```

You can see more details here : [Loading local files to UIWebView](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/loading-local-files-into-uiwebview/)

Comment: I don't think helps me unless I save the image locally?

Comment: oh sorry, I thought that you wanted to save locally. It was my fault.:(

Answer (score 4):

```
UIImage *screenshot= [UIImage imageAtPath:
                              [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MfLogo_aboutus" ofType:@"png"]]; 
NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot); 
[vc addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"logo.png"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load urlImage into webview which is not saved locally as shown below code

```
NSString *str = @"";
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:7agzdcFyZ715EM:http://files.walerian.info/Funny/Animals/funny-pictures-firefox-file-transfer-is-complete.jpg"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
        [webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/jpg" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found somewhere else that you have to provide a value in the `baseUR`L parameter. I also had encoding set:

```
textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/"]];
```

When I had `nil` in the `baseURL` parameter it would not load. By putting something that's basically irrelevant in there the MS docs all worked.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try assigning a delegate to the webview and implementing the method:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

To see more specifically what error you're getting.  If it doesn't get called, implement the method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

as well, just to make sure *something* is happening, otherwise there might be an issue with `UIWebView` (assuming you haven't returned `NO` from `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`)

Comment: it doesn't fail with an error, but it does call the finishload method. Perhaps you can't just pass it the data for the image, you need to wrap it in HTML somehow?

Comment: If you want to try wrapping it in HTML, you can always use a data: URL, which base-64-encodes images (or anything, really) as data in the HTML document.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML for an example.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ed Marty's comment:

The HTML command to put in a base 64 image is:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,##PUT THE BASE64 DATA HERE###" />
```

I have a category (I'm not sure where it came from, not me...) available on my website that converts NSData to it's Base64 string representation.

[Header](http://www.webmoco.com/files/NSData+Base64.m)
[Implementation](http://www.webmoco.com/files/NSData+Base64.m)

Easy enough to do, assuming 'imageData' is the NSData variable containing your image:
[imageData base64Encoding] into the above string.

Comment: These links don't work anymore. Do you happen to know where they have gone please?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
// 1) Get: Get string from “outline.plist” in the “DrillDownSave”-codesample.
savedUrlString = [item objectForKey: @"itemUrl"];

// 2) Set: The url in string-format, excluding the html-appendix.
NSString *tempUrlString = savedUrlString;

// 3) Set: Format a url-string correctly. The html-file is located locally.
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tempUrlString ofType:@”html”];

// 4) Set: Set an “NSData”-object of the url-sting.
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];

// 5. Gets the path to the main bundle root folder
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

// 6. Need to be double-slashes to work correctly with UIWebView, so change all “/” to “//”
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];

// 7. Also need to replace all spaces with “%20″
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

//  Load:   Loads the local html-page.
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];
```

Comment: You might want to indicate that you copied this word-for-word from here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=613532

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method:

Save the image you downloaded into your documents folder.
Then get that image's url. Then write a simple html file
using that image url in the IMG SRC tag.

```
NSLog(@"url=%@", fileURL); // fileURL is the image url in doc folder of your app


//get the documents directory:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/toOpen.html",
                      documentsDirectory];

//create simple html file and format the url into the IMG SRC tag
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=%@></body></html>",fileURL];
//save content to the documents directory
[content writeToFile:fileName
          atomically:NO
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
               error:nil]; // now we have a HTML file in our doc

// open the HTML file we wrote in the webview

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"life.html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[yourWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *pathForFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"fireballscopy" ofType: @"gif"];
    NSData *dataOfGif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathForFile];
    [Web_View loadData:dataOfGif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```