# NSData into UIWebView with MIME type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiwebview, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct way to load image into UIWebView from NSData object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827891/correct-way-to-load-image-into-uiwebview-from-nsdata-object)

I am having `NSData` downloaded from server for which i am having `MIME` type also. But i dont know how to load this `NSData` into `UIWebView`.

I just tried it as,

```
[mywebView loadData:myData MIMEType:myMimeType textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

My mime type is something similar to @"image/jpeg".

But all i am getting is white blank screen. I have refered few documents, nothing helped me.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827891/correct-way-to-load-image-into-uiwebview-from-nsdata-object

Comment: its just a simple problem with my mime type. After changing the mime type into @"image/pjpeg" now it woks fine.