# UIWebView for GIF Background loadData method error

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, gif, swift2

I keep receiving the same error of: Cannot invoke loadData with an argument of list type '(NSData, MIMEType: String, textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)'

for the loadData method.

```
var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fractal", ofType: "gif")

var gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

var webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)

webViewBG.loadData(gif!,MIMEType: "image/gif",textEncodingName: nil,baseURL: nil) // this line of code causes the build error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `loadData` function signature, which is:

```
func loadData(_ data: NSData, MIMEType MIMEType: String,
  textEncodingName textEncodingName: String, baseURL baseURL: NSURL)
```

`textEncodingName` is `String`, not `String?`, thus you can't pass `nil`. Same applies to `baseURL` where the type is `NSURL`, not `NSURL?`.

In this case, you can pass *whatever* values like `utf-8` and `http://localhost/` to meet *non-nil* criteria.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827891/correct-way-to-load-image-into-uiwebview-from-nsdata-object) for other ways how to do it.

Try to minimize usage of `!` to avoid runtime failures. Something like this is much more robust:

```
guard let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fractal", ofType: "gif"),
  let gifData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) else {
    return
}

var webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webViewBG.loadData(gifData, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "utf-8",
  baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/")!)
```

Comment: func loadData(data: NSData!, MIMEType: String!, textEncodingName: String!, baseURL: NSURL!). how to pass argument to this func ? i was use this : webView.loadData("test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false), MIMEType: "text/html" , textEncodingName: NSUTF8StringEncoding , baseURL: nil) but not work!