# Swift 3: Load GIF in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, gif

I want to load GIF in my swift 3 application. I used this code to do that but the gif is not showed.

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: “myGif”, ofType: "gif")
let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
self.webView.load(gif! as Data, mimeType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
self.webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code (I'm really new to swift and iOS development).

Any help please?

Comment: Unrelated by why do you use `NSData(contentsOfFile:)` instead of `Data(contentsOf:options:)`? Use Swift classes, especially when the next line casts the Cocoa class to a Swift class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to load image into UIWebView from NSData object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827891/correct-way-to-load-image-into-uiwebview-from-nsdata-object)

Comment: @rmaddy because I got this error when I use Data: Argument labels '(contentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: @Ryan sorry but it's not a duplicated question. I use swift and not objective-c

Comment: @Llg Right because it's `Data(contentsOf:options:)`, not `Data(contentsOfFile:)`.

Comment: @rmaddy please what have I to put for the options? I used this but it seems that it's not working `Data(contentsOf: URL(string:filePath!)!, options:nil)`

Comment: @Llg Are you sure that `NSData(contentOfFile: filePath!)` is not nil? Also `textEncodingName` can't be `String()`.

Comment: @Ryan for the NSData(contentOfFile: filePath!) I can see its number of bytes when I debug, so it's not nil. Can you give me please a working example so I can understand more and more?

Comment: @Llg That's the wrong initializer to create a `URL` from a file path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [SwiftGif Lbrary](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif) from github, it doesn't use webview (if you want to use webview write me to comments to update the answer)

EDIT:

Webview:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "source", withExtension: "gif")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
webview.load(data, mimeType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
webview.scalesPageToFit = true
webview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I have already found this repo but I use swift 3 and ios 8+. Can you please give me the webview version?

Comment: @Llg it is for swift 3 I just tested in xcode 8 (but I will update it with webview)

Comment: @Llg Ryan has answered your question first, test his code it's working.

Comment: Yes it works thanks! Can you please see my comment in Ryan's answer?

Comment: I didn't test it because I don't have a big gif but try to change from storyboard, select the webview and then from the right menu change content mode to aspect fit

Comment: Thank a lot! I will test it. Excuse me if I ask a lot of questions but how to let the gif always playing? My gif stop animating after a little time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128746/discussion-between-mike-vorisis-and-llg).

Comment: @Llg did you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Here is working example. I downloaded the gif image from web and added it to sample project.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "hsk", withExtension: "gif")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
webView.load(data, mimeType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
```

With the code above, I could see the animated gif as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works! What if the webview size is less than the gif? In other words I want to put in into a small webview but I want to show all the content of the gif (I don't want to scroll to see the hidden parts of the gif )

Comment: There's a way to check webView's contentSize and maybe you can write a html/css to shrink size of gif. If you use webView just to display animated gif, you can fetch data and animate it with `UIImageView` or you can use 3rd party library like [Gifu](https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. A last question please: how to keep the gif always playing? My gif stop animating after a little time

Comment: Not sure as long as you use `UIWebView`. If you use `UIImageView`, you can run animation repeatedly or you can stop whenever you want.

Comment: Can I use `UIImageView` with GIF? I yes can you please provide me an example?

Comment: That was what I said in previous comment. Maybe you can refer the source code of `Gifu`.

Comment: I didn't use it because my min ios target deployment is iOS 8 and the Gifu requires the iOS 9

Comment: There are many 3rd party library to handle animated gif in `UIImageView`. Search it. It is even out of topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128748/discussion-between-ryan-and-llg).